# Drupal image upload module for tinymce (IMCE) - permissions

Tags: image, drupal, permissions, tinymce

I am using Drupal image upload module for tinymce. I am able to 
upload and manage file uploads as admin.  However I am unable to 
assign this task to another profile.  I get full edit screen,
but I am missing upload button. I gave profile the follwing permissions:

access tinymce
administer tinymce
administer tinytinymce

use tinytinymce advanced
use tinytinymce simple

administer files

upload files
view uploaded files

*Update*

I just tried giving the profile *every* permission and cannot get the upload icon. :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have updates or additional information regarding your question, please edit your question rather than posting new items below. All posts below ought to be answers only.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to "Create configuration profiles and assign them to user roles at /admin/settings/imce," as described in step 3 of the *Installation* section in the IMCE module's [README.txt file](http://drupalcode.org/viewvc/drupal/contributions/modules/imce/README.txt?revision=1.12.2.5&view=markup&pathrev=DRUPAL-6--2-1).

Comment: The linked image is no longer available! But still, this answer is valid and should be accepted...